# What is an expected conversion rate in a free to play game?

Tags: business, free-to-play

I understand that there's a lot of factors at play that decide how much free users will become paid users. What can be expected from different marketing strategies such as selling non-gameplay impacting items, selling gameplay impacting items, selling subscriptions, etc? An ideal answer would have statistics showing numbers from different games?

Comment: Make a game first, not a monetization plan. If you don't have substance, no matter how appealing the purchaseable items are, there's nobody to buy them

Comment: Please stick to the question, I am working on a game that has been in development since 2016. We already have something working with players.

Comment: Just googling "free to play conversion rate" turns up quite a few discussions of expected ranges on the very first page of results. Is there some aspect to this you haven't been able to answer from your own research to date?

Comment: Hi DMGregory,  this is the part that I was not able to find online.

```What can be expected from different marketing strategies such as selling non-gameplay impacting items, selling gameplay impacting items, selling subscriptions, etc```

I could categorize the games to get the data, but I fear that it will be highly inaccurate due to different games having a different target audience. I think that conversion rates per selling strategy within the same game or company would be optimal.

Comment: This information tends to be tightly held by companies, having been acquired through excruciating and expensive trial-and-error.

Comment: This is a sufficiently deep research subject that I doubt you'll get answers to the detail you're describing from unpaid volunteers here. You could hire a paid research assistant to investigate published data and benchmarks and distill a theory of how the results correlate with target demographics and strategic decisions, or you could do this research yourself. Waiting for someone to hand it to you for free when they could make a reasonable consulting fee for the same work, you could be waiting for a very long time.

Comment: This should probably be closed as too broad, but I'd suggest you spend some time watching the various videos by Extra Credits on youtube. They pretty regularly discuss the subject of monetization strategies and the impacts each strategy have on the players. Common thread I see is that selling power (i.e. selling non-cosmetic items) will generally kill your player base, so should be approached with extreme care.